# How do I fill the rest of my screen design with blank frames in tkinter using for loop?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to make a shopping-inspired vending machine UI. The goal is to fill up my frame with frames using for loop and 2D list, then pack on buttons and labels onto it. Codes are as followed:

```
    frames = []
    frame_order = []
    num = 0

    for x in range(5):
        frames.append([])
        for y in range(5):
            frames[x].append(5)

    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            frames[x][y] = Frame(store_canvas, width=1520 / 5, height=1030 / 5, bd = 2, relief = SOLID)
            frames[x][y].grid(row=y, column=x)
            frames[x][y].pack_propagate(False)
            frame_order.append(frames[x][y])
```

This will reun an SQL query database that will return with an item list as a `list[]`.Then fill up the frames inside the 2D `list`

```
retrieve_tiem()
```

I have also set up another frame on the side that has other filters. the problem is that if the filter query SQL and returns with an `item list` less than the grid size (5x5, a total of 25 items) then the `for` loop won't run as it cannot populate. to avoid this, I tried to use `Try` and `Except` but the loop would just fill the remaining space with buttons instead.

```
for frame in frame_order:
    try:
        Button(frame, anchor='nw', height = 9, width = 35, font = 20).pack()
        Label(frame, text=str(Item_list[num]), anchor='nw', font = 20, width = 35, bg = 'darkgreen', fg = 'yellow' ).pack()
        num += 1
    except:
        pass
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Like not creating the button when the Item list run out off item or fill the rest of the list with `'*blank*'` until the list reach the total amount of item that the frame can hold? I am also open to other methods too if it works. All answer are appreciated, please go easy on me as I am still learning python and SQL:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use 1-D list instead of 2-D list.  Below is an example based on your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

store_canvas = Frame(root)
store_canvas.pack()

# create the 25 frames
ROWS = COLS = 5
MAX_ITEMS = ROWS * COLS
frames = []
for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
    frames.append(Frame(store_canvas, width=1520/COLS, height=1030/ROWS, bd=2, relief=SOLID))
    frames[-1].grid(row=i//COLS, column=i%COLS)
    frames[-1].pack_propagate(False)

# function to simulate retrieving data from database table
def retrieve_tiem():
    return [f"Item #{i+1}" for i in range(random.randint(1,MAX_ITEMS))]

# function to show the retrieved items
def update_list():
    Item_list = retrieve_tiem()
    label_font = ("Arial", 20)
    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        for w in frame.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
        if i < len(Item_list):
            item = Item_list[i]
            Button(frame).pack(fill="both", expand=1)
            Label(frame, text=item, font=label_font, bg="darkgreen", fg="yellow").pack(fill="x")

update_list()
root.bind("<F5>", lambda e: update_list())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I ran the code in a separate file and the effect is exactly what I wanted, However, I am struggling to understand some parts of the code and what it actually does so if possible can you please explain it to me briefly? I hope im not asking too much:

1. for the frame.grid, why does the [-1] is -1?

2. what does {} means?

3. what does `enumerate` means, what does it do?

Comment: @Y0SHI0N 1) `frames[-1]` means the last item in the list `frames`; 2) `f"{...}"` will evaluate the expression inside `{}` and put the result in the f-string; 3) See official document on [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

Comment: UPDATE: since the previous comment; I tried to copy and paste the code in, and tweak the variables and it works like a charm...thank you so much... I still have no clue why it works though lul:)

EDIT: oops didn't see your comments, thanks for the explaination, I'll look into the links

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `try` statement. Here's an example:

```
a = 5
try:
    a += 7
    int("str") #This is just to raise an exception
except:
    pass
```

After running this code, the value of `a` will be 12, even though an error occured. This is the same thing that is happening in your code. The line that creates the button is run successfully, but the creating the label raises an exception. This is why you get buttons in the remaining space. This can be resolved using `else`.
If we try this instead:

```
a = 5
try:
    int("str") #This is just to raise an exception
except:
    pass
else:
    a += 7
```

The `a += 7` line will only be run if there is not exception in the `try` statement, so the value will remain 5. For your code, this will be

```
try:
    Item_list[num] #This is what causes the error
except:
    pass
else:
    Button(frame, anchor='nw', height = 9, width = 35, font = 20).pack()
    Label(frame, text=str(Item_list[num]), anchor='nw', font = 20, width = 35, bg = 'darkgreen', fg = 'yellow' ).pack()
    num += 1
```

Alternatively, you could have an `if` statement to check if `num` is larger than the length of the data returned, but there's not enough information in the question for me to be sure that will work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I make sense to me why that happens now.