# How to detect which button is pressed to call up a command specific to it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a vending machine UI, Which has 25 buttons  generated dymanically using this code:

```
    def retrieve_tiem(): #SQL query to reteive item into Item_List[]

    ROWS = COLS = 5
    MAX_ITEMS = ROWS * COLS
    frames = []
    for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
        frames.append(Frame(store_canvas, width=1520 / COLS, height=1030 / ROWS, bd=2, relief=SOLID))
        frames[-1].grid(row=i // COLS, column=i % COLS)
        frames[-1].pack_propagate(False)

    def update_list():
        label_font = ("Arial", 15)
        for i,frame in enumerate(frames):
            for w in frame.winfo_children():
                w.destroy()
            if i < len(Item_list):
                item = Item_list[i]
                Button(frame).pack(fill="both", expand=1)
                Label(frame, text=Item_list[i], font=label_font, bg="darkgreen", fg="yellow").pack(fill="x")
```

The context of how I got to this code and its bg are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313182/how-do-i-fill-the-rest-of-my-screen-design-with-blank-frames-in-tkinter-using-fo). I want to be able to use the button to call upon a top-level widget to display the correct Item for sale corresponding to that button. However, the grid generated by this code will be dynamically reduced or increase depending on the filter options that the users pick. This means that no button can hold the same 'ID' to be called everytime. I looked online first and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539787/determine-which-button-was-pressed-in-tkinter) somewhat similar problem. The only downside is that the button in that post are fixed and don't move around. Is there a way for me to achieve the mentioned effect? Also regarding the similar linked post, could it be that it would work for me but I just happen to logically analysed it wrong? All answers are much appreciated.

EDIT:
For those who would like a quick, reproduced result of what the buttons would behave like when the number of items increase or decrease based on the filters, here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

store_canvas = Frame(root)
store_canvas.pack()

# create the 25 frames
ROWS = COLS = 5
MAX_ITEMS = ROWS * COLS
frames = []
for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
    frames.append(Frame(store_canvas, width=1520/COLS, height=1030/ROWS, bd=2, relief=SOLID))
    frames[-1].grid(row=i//COLS, column=i%COLS)
    frames[-1].pack_propagate(False)

# function to simulate retrieving data from database table
def retrieve_tiem():
    return [f"Item #{i+1}" for i in range(random.randint(1,MAX_ITEMS))]

# function to show the retrieved items
def update_list():
    Item_list = retrieve_tiem()
    label_font = ("Arial", 20)
    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        for w in frame.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
        if i < len(Item_list):
            item = Item_list[i]
            Button(frame).pack(fill="both", expand=1)
            Label(frame, text=item, font=label_font, bg="darkgreen", fg="yellow").pack(fill="x")

update_list()
root.bind("<F5>", lambda e: update_list())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you labeled the buttons, instead of using a separate label, you could read the label in the button-push-handler.

Comment: Why are you using `grid` and `pack_propagate`?

Comment: @TheLizzard I am using `grid` to place it on the canvas, and `pack_propagates` is there to prevent anything that is placed within the frame ( aka the buttons and labels) to cause the frame to shrink to fit its sizes.

Comment: I think you wanted to use `grid_propagate`. I would be very surprised if removing the `pack_propagates` from your code would change anything.

Comment: Since you retrieved the items from database, there should be an unique ID for each item.  Pass that unique ID to the callback of the button.

Comment: @acw1668 yes, but its a bit more complicated than that, the items ID are indeed different but the only difference between items with the same name and different ID is their size. So I would like to call `topclass` based on their name, then retrieve different sizes as a drop box menu. If that make sense to you?

Comment: @TheLizzard I think you would be wrong since the frame will shrink back into the size of the item store within it. That being said, I have removed it as an experiment and they indeed did change.

Comment: Then you can pass the item name to the button callback.

Comment: @acw1668 dumb question.... I can do that? Sorry I am stiill very inexperience with coding

Comment: If `Item_list` contains the item names, then use `Button(frame, command=lambda name=item: show_item(name))`.  Create the function `def show_item(name)` and do whatever you want based on the passed item name inside that function.

Comment: @acw1668 so instead of making 20 different functions, we are making 1 with 25 different conditions, each one for an item?

Comment: @TheLizzard no, I think you are misunderstanding.the pack propagate is for everything that is inside the frame, the placement method of the frame on something else vs the placement method of everything else in the frame is separate and it doesnt matter if we mix between place, pack or girid at all. (is in in reply to your discussion msg, sorry i cant reply because my repu got -10 for some reason)

Comment: @Y0SHI0N ok my bad. I forgot that the `pack_propagate` works on the children of the frame not on the parent of the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the solution suggested by @acw1668 in the comment section above, I passed the item's name through to the function using `Button(frame, command=lambda name=item: show_item(name))`, Then crated function `def show_item(name)` and automatically, I can do whatever I want with the passed item's name. An examplar code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

store_canvas = Frame(root)
store_canvas.pack()

# create the 25 frames
ROWS = COLS = 5
MAX_ITEMS = ROWS * COLS
frames = []
for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
    frames.append(Frame(store_canvas, width=1520/COLS, height=1030/ROWS, bd=2, relief=SOLID))
    frames[-1].grid(row=i//COLS, column=i%COLS)
    frames[-1].pack_propagate(False)

# function to simulate retrieving data from database table
def retrieve_tiem():
    return [f"Item #{i+1}" for i in range(random.randint(1,MAX_ITEMS))]

# function to show the retrieved items
def update_list():
    Item_list = retrieve_tiem()
    label_font = ("Arial", 20)
    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        for w in frame.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
        if i < len(Item_list):
            item = Item_list[i]
            Button(frame, command=lambda name=item: show_item(name)).pack(fill="both", expand=1)
            Label(frame, text=item, font=label_font, bg="darkgreen", fg="yellow").pack(fill="x")

def show_item(name):
    print(name)


update_list()
root.bind("<F5>", lambda e: update_list())
root.mainloop()
```

Once again, thank you @acw1668 for your answer.